# Solve ODE $y'' + (y')^2 + y = \ln(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $y'' + (y')^2 + y = \ln(x)$ with boundary conditions $y(1) = 0$ and $y(2) = \ln(2)$. The solution is $y = \ln(x)$ but I don't know how to start the problem.

Comment: You mean other than "by inspection, it works"?

Comment: have to numerically solve the ode

Comment: You can maybe do substitution $t(x)=\ln(x), x = \exp(t)$ and express $y,y',y''$ in $t$ instead.

Comment: Actually all solutions to $y'' + (y')^2 = 0$ are shifted logarithms, and the boundary data fixes it to the unshifted logarithm.

Comment: @CalvinKhor How exactly is that helpful? The equation you mentioned is not the equation given by OP, and as it is nonlinear, homogeneity is unhelpful.

Comment: It is merely an observation, and one made two years ago. if I knew if it was helpful, I probably would have written an answer…?

Comment: @Angel I recall the following thought process. Observe that if we can show that the(ok, a) solution is $y=\ln x$, then it must be also a solution to the simpler problem I mentioned. In the reverse direction, if you solve the simpler problem, with the given boundary data, you end up with $y=\ln x$, and the same algebra gives you a solution to the full problem. I left it as a comment because this is far from a full description of the solutions.

Comment: PS I did not vote on your Answer, but I have no idea what you are doing (and the barrage of exp makes it tiring to try to understand). In addition, a more thin-skinned keyboard warrior may interpret "How exactly is that helpful?" in an antagonistic manner, or maybe even take offense on my behalf (such people exist)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Your explanation does help. Without the explanation, though, your comment just felt as though it added no information that could be used to come up with a solution. Also, personally, I tend to not concern myself with people who are so thin-skinned. If they get angry, then it is what it is. Regarding my own answer, I wrote late at night, and looking back on it, it was itself very unhelpful, so I ended up deleting it. To give context to what I was trying to achieve, though, I basically did a change of a variables in a way that was careful, and the resulting equation...

Comment: ...and the resulting equation is an equation that should have been easier to solve. However, I realize that the equation was still undesirably complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Answer

Take $$u(x)=ln(x)-y$$   so $$u'=1/x-y'$$ and $$u''=-1/x^2-y''$$

We have:
$$u''+(2/x)u'-(u')^2+u'=0$$
Now, we employ the substitution $$p(x)=u'$$ It is immediate that
$$p'+(2/x)p=p^2-p$$

$$p(x)= 1/(x*(c1*x*exp(x)+x*Ei(-x)+1))$$

Now continue...

Note: if there any mistakes in the answer, feel free to edit in the corrections or comment them

Comment: If $u(x)=\ln(x)-y(x),$ then $y''(x)+y'(x)^2+y(x)=\ln(x)$ is equivalent to $\ln''(x)-u''(x)+[\ln'(x)-u'(x)]^2=u(x)=-\frac1{x^2}-u''(x)+\frac1{x^2}-\frac{2u'(x)}{x}+u'(x)^2=-u''(x)+u'(x)^2-\frac{2u'(x)}{x}.$ This is equivalent to $u''(x)+\frac{2u'(x)}{x}-u'(x)^2+u(x)=0,$ not $u''(x)+\frac{2u'(x)}{x}-u'(x)^2+u'(x)=0,$ the latter being what you wrote. As such, the substitution $p(x)=u'(x)$ is not feasible. That is the mistake.

Comment: Restart with substituting $u$, but now take $v=-(e^u)'=e^uu'$. Then $v'+(\frac2x+1)v$ is linear or separable. $x^2e^xv(x)=C$ leads to similar expressions as your last.